# ddev WSL2 Magento 2 multistore set $MAGE_RUN_CODE & $MAGE_RUN_TYPE

Tags: magento2, ddev

Anyone know how can set the $MAGE_RUN_CODE & $MAGE_RUN_TYPE variables for a Magento 2 multi site using ddev-local?
I have added the new domain to the additional_hostnames variable in .ddev/config.yaml - but now I need to tell the nginx docker container to serve the magento store front when that newstorefront.ddev.site domain is requested.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got this working by overriding the .ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf and adding the following lines towards the top of the server block (just before where it defines `if ($mage_run_code = '') {`:

```
if ($http_host = mysecondsite.ddev.site){
    set $mage_run_code 'mysecondsite_en';
    set $mage_run_type store;
}
```

Now it all works correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In ddev you can set environment variables globally or locally in the config, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-environment-variables-to-a-container

Basic idea: add this to your .ddev/config.yaml:

```yaml
web_environment:
- MAGE_RUN_CODE =someval
- MAGE_RUN_TYPE =someotherval
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do i do that for the new domain? I think setting it like you suggest will affect the main sites configuration - not the add on domains

Comment: I'm not very familiar with magento, but if you want to have multiple docroots, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#multiple-docroots-in-nginx-advanced -

Comment: Would you do what you want using a .env file?

Comment: Thanks, but it’s not something that is controlled via the env.php file.

Comment: Have just re read your comment and realised I’d misread it. How would I configure it in the env file?

Comment: That's a magento-specific question that I'm not competent for. As far as ddev, remember it's just like any other webserver environment, it just happens to be running on your computer. So if you already do this in production... or plan to do so in production... the answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up multistore configuration:

In your project folder `MAGENTO_ROOT_FOLDER/.ddev/nginx_full` add a `magento-stores.conf` containing the following:

```
map $http_host $mage_run_code {
    default '';
    store1.ddev.site storecode1;
    store2.ddev.site storecode2;
    store3.ddev.site storecode3;
}
```

Next, open up your project's `MAGENTO_ROOT_FOLDER/.ddev/config.yaml` and add additional hostnames:

```yaml
additional_hostnames:
  - store1
  - store2
  - store3
```

Source: https://github.com/jellesiderius/ddev-magento2-setup?tab=readme-ov-file#setting-up-multistore-configuration